# Maria DB Communication Link failure exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, mariadb

I am developing application  using "Spring Boot + Maria B ". I don't have any issue while using in local environment. Its working as expected.
When we move the same code into Production server I'm facing strange database access issue.

Production technologies are Tomcat 9.0, Spring Boot 1.3.3 and Maria DB 10.0 versions

Am able to connect to the production DB through standalone java application

[image: Production Standalone result]

but when i try to deploy the application into production tomcat server am facing communication link failure exception.

[image: Production Tomcat Server]

Can anyone please help me to resolve communication link failure issue.

```
server.contextPath=/ah8
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mysql
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=<password>

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.datasource.continueOnError: true
spring.datasource.initialize: false
spring.datasource.initialSize: 0
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
spring.datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 5000
spring.datasource.minIdle: 0
```

Comment: Can you add the code snippets used for connecting to DB?

Comment: Uday thanks for your quick response, i have updated my question with properties xml of spring boot. and i have added images , unfortunately images are appearing with hyperlink

Comment: The only reason I can see is the wrong driver being used. Thr correct driver for maria db is `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`. Try updating it and let me know. Refer to http://sterl.org/2015/09/spring-boot-mariadb/ for more details.

Comment: Would be nice to now what kind of exceptions... Exception codes, stack traces, error messages but your post contains none of those. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with that refreshed knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Uday, after changing necessary changes, its working fine, you saved my day, thank you very much

Comment: Hi Deinum, thanks for editing, as am new to stackoverflow and this is my first question, next time onwards i will keep in mind all your suggestions, but i have attached the images, unfortunately those images are came as hyperlinks, if we click the production standalone result and production tomcat server link, we can see the stacktrace

Comment: You shouldn't include stack traces as images etc. just add them as code. Provide as much information as you can give and don't let people click links to get a full picture as that will keep people from answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can see is the wrong driver being used. Thr correct driver for maria db is `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`. Refer to sterl.org/2015/09/spring-boot-mariadb for more details.